# Items in a 2d tile based game

Tags: java, roguelike

I am making a 2d tile based game in Java, and I was wondering what the best way to store items in the world was. In the past i have always used an array the same size of the world but I want to make really big worlds, and I know for a fact this would be a bad idea. So I was just wondering what the best way would be?

Comment: java.util.List or java.util.Map depending on how you want to look things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the type of your tiles e.g. by an **int**, you could use one bit of it to indicates if there is an item.
The item itself you store in a List ordered by x coordinates (and if the x coordinate is the same, than use the y coordinate as second ordering property).

This way you can detect, if there is an item on the tile very fast (**O(1)** and than search in the `List<Item>` only if there is an item. On the list you can use binary search (first related to the x coordinate, and within the sublist of all items with the same x coordinate use binary search for the wanted y coordinate) **O(log(n))** [n = number of items].

If you want to save memory, I would consider using an elementar data type to specify the tile (e.g. an `int`) and store your world e.g. in an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

A list of items alongwith their (x,y) co-ordinates should work fine for really huge worlds as well.

Comment: Even if 99% of the array was set to null, it would still take up as much memory as if they were all full, so I was hoping for something for efficient

Comment: To store the list use one of the containers from java.util e.g. java.util.ArrayList or java.util.List